# UICollectionView - replicate Photos.app functionality

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a UICollectionView that behaves like the photos.app on the iPad (pinch to group and expand).

How do you think photos.app is built?

- Is it one UICollectionView with one layout, and the pinch just does a
  batch update and moves cells in to sections?
- Or is it one UICollectionView with two different layout?
- Or the last option, could it be two UICollectionViews?

What do you think is the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the second suggestion - two different layouts.

I'd recommend checking the almost identical example in iOS6 by Turorials book (paid content, but probably worth it in your case).

http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-6-by-tutorials

Comment: That's good since that's the way I've built it so far. I've been a constant visitor to that site but haven't bought the book yet. But probably will now.

Answer (score 6):

In case you didn't buy the book yet,
I also wrote a blog post about the basic idea (and some code for the flow layout subclass).

http://thyraz.tumblr.com/post/35135290759/stacklayout